# Appending key value pairs to a dictionary based on returned values from a for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to organize a file containing list of medical records into sets of values that are relevant from each record. I have divided them up and am now trying to organize them into a dictionary containing the record unique ID and returned values for each record. I am a bit stuck at the end, but the background is listed below.

This function below breaks a file of multiple records into individual records:

```
def recordList(file_path):
    with open(file_path) as f:
        chunk = []
        for line in f:
            if 'FIRST_WORD' in line:
                if chunk:
                    yield "".join(chunk)
                chunk = [line]
            else:
                chunk.append(line) 
        if chunk:
            yield "".join(chunk)

xx = recList(file_name)    #CAN'T print xx since its a generator fun
yy = list(xx)  #CAN print yy and view all the records, or check indiv records
                  e.g. print yy[4] prints out the 4th record
```

I then create a dictionary of values of interest within each record, and a function that looks for those values in a record and returns them:

```
pdict= {}

pdict = {
"ID": r"(ID: )(reg expression for ID number)",
"Name": r"(NAME:)([A-Z]{0,20}\s{0,3}[A-Z]{0,20})(\s+SPC)"
"Date": r"(DATE DRAWN:\s)(\d..\d\d.\d\d)"
"Key1": r"(Key1: )(reg expression for key1 value)",
"Key2": r"(Key2: )(reg expression for key2 value)",
}


#Function that searches for patterns above within a record

def paramGetter(pattern, record): 
seeker = re.search(pattern, record)
if seeker:
    return (seeker.group(2))
else:
    return None
```

As the final task, I am creating a new dictionary of all records and returned values. The key will be the ID number + Date for each record (a unique identifier combo), and values will be all extracted parameters (rec_params above) for each record. The below works for an individual record, here #20, and does that task. However, I am unsure how to get it to go through the whole file and append these dictionaries to the master dictionary as it goes. I tried str(yy) in place of yy[20] but got an error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
rec_params = {} 
masterDict = {}

for record in yy:
    for key in pdict.keys():
        res =  paramGetter(pdict[key], yy[20])
        if res:
            rec_params[key] = res
    UNIQUE_ID = str(rec_params['ID'] + "-" + rec_params['Date'])
    masterDict = {UNIQUE_ID: rec_params}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code here, but lets just look at this:

```
masterDict = {}                                                                 # 1
                                                                                # 2
for record in recList(file_path):                                               # 3
    for key in pdict.keys():                                                    # 4
        res =  paramGetter(pdict[key], record)                                  # 5
        if res:                                                                 # 6
            rec_params[key] = res                                               # 7
        for key in masterDict.keys():                                           # 8
            masterDict[key]= str(rec_params["ID"] + "-" + rec_params["Date"])   # 9
        for value in masterDict.values():                                       # 10
            masterDict[value]= rec_params                                       # 11
```

The only parts where you're (attempting to) insert into `masterDict` are lines 9 and 11.

But since `masterDict` is empty, you'll never get to lines 9 or 11 (since you'll never enter the body of `for` loops on lines 8 and 10 -- since `masterDict` is empty.  Its a "chicken or the egg"-type problem at the moment.

Perhaps you want to initialize `masterDict` prior to line 3 with some default values, or iterate over something else on lines 8 and 10.

Comment: Thanks! I edited it to the above, and it now works for single records. However, I am having difficulty getting it to do it for each record in the master file. I tried it with a str(yy) and print masterDict at the end, but it goes crazy and prints them multiple times indefinitely.  I also tried other variations of yy to try and specify that it should only look in each record (e.g. yy(record)) before filling the dictionary and moving on but no luck. f you have any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it, I just started a programing course a month ago and I am finding it really challenging

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any obvious places  where you have defined `rec_params` which means that if we entered the condition in line 7 (as per jedward's helpful line numbers) we should hit a `NameError`. So print the result assigned to `res` to confirm that it is behaving as expected.
If in fact you have defined it somewhere then try the following, see how you get on:

```
masterDict = {}

for record in recList(file_path):
    for key in pdict.keys():
        res =  paramGetter(pdict[key], record)
        if res:
            rec_params[key] = res 
            master_key = str(rec_params["ID"] + "-" + rec_params["Date"])
            masterDict[master_key] = rec_params
```

Also assigning `key` twice within a nested for loop might not be a good idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me get it to the above format, but I am still having trouble getting it to loop through the whole file (it doesn't accept record for the intake in paramGetter, and won't work with a string of the whole file). I had to pull back the indentation for the Unique ID and masterDict lines though or it was telling me that ID was undefined. YY is just the variable for the list form of recList(file_path), but I tried it with both. Thanks again! This was very helpful!!!

Comment: Glad to have helped. I think you have hard-coded `yy[20]` as a parameter in the construct `res =  paramGetter(pdict[key], yy[20])` instead of `record` as before. See if that solves the problem.